# XLSX(excel) file not exporting using amcharts

Tags: javascript, php, charts, export-to-excel, amcharts

i have try to export amcharts chart data in excel file but not exporting and no error display
rather than XLSX format other format file exporting like csv

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataProvider": [{
        "country": "USA",
        "visits": 2025

    }, {
        "country": "Brazil",
        "visits": 395
    }],

    "valueAxes": [{
        "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "gridAlpha": 0.2,
        "dashLength": 0
    }],
    "gridAboveGraphs": true,
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "visits"
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "zoomable": false
    },
    "categoryField": "country",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "tickPosition": "start",
        "tickLength": 20
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true,
        "menu": [{
            "class": "export-main",
            "menu": [{
                "label": "Excel",
                "menu": ["XLSX", "CSV"]
            }]
        }],
    }
});
```

using this code export to csv success but not in XLSX formate and not any error show

Comment: The code exports to XLSX correctly for me. Are you loading the amcharts libraries directly from the CDN or are you hosting them locally? If it's the latter, make sure you have all of the supporting files from the export plugin (xlsx.js, etc). Otherwise, please create a runnable snippet (or fiddle) instead of just your chart code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: thank you,i missing xlsx.js,now working perfectly